# Extracting Pixel Data at (x,y) from an external Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function which should read a .jpg or .png file and **return** the pixel data at position(x,y) using Javascript . I have tried using getImagedata(), but that doesn't solve the purpose as I am not able to **return** the value using this .

Comment: What do you mean you are "not able to return the value using this"?. `GetImageData` returns an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object. Are you wanting to transform [ImageData.data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) into what you want?

Comment: if by external you mean cross site - it can't be done without the proper authority (CORS?) of the source of the image

Comment: @httpNick , I am trying to make an array containing all the ImageData . Or rather make any mechanisms that I could get hold of the value from outside the onload function ?

Comment: @JaromandaX .. By external I mean an image not rendered by the javascript code .